# 'initial' argument must come first when creating django form?

Tags: django, forms

I have this working code

```
f = SomeForm(request.POST)
```

When I tried to modify it into

```
f = SomeForm(request.POST, initial={'spam', 4})
```

it didnt work, the 'initial' wasnt selected ('spam' is a ModelChoiceField), but when I tried

```
f = SomeForm(initial={'spam', 4})
```

it worked (selected value was correct). Am I missing something here? If it matters, heres what its **init** method looks like

```
def __init__(self, *a, **ka):
    super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*a, **ka)
    ....#more codes
```

Is there a way to make the initial data works without having to remove the first argument? Thank you

EDIT : it doesnt have to be "initial", as long as I can put some pre-determined value on ModelChoiceField. The condition = There is a request.POST, but the form hasnt been submitted (the post came from another page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I only had to change the data attribute. Use copy method to make QueryDict mutable

```
post = request.POST.copy()

f = SomeForm(post)
f.data['spam'] = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass `initial` if the form has been posted. Check `request.method` and instantiate the form accordingly.

Comment: thanks, but the POST came from another page via action post, so the form hasnt been posted yet. whats the best approach for this?

Comment: You could pass POST as initial: `SomeForm( initial = request.POST )` or just modify `request.POST` before passing if as data to the form `if not request.POST.get("spam"): request.POST["spam"] = 4`